# Why switchMap does not require an observable when returning an simple array

Tags: rxjs, observable, switchmap

I was originally searching how to return several actions in a ngrx effect, and found I need to return an array of actions.

Then I noticed that returning a simple array in the switchMap works as fine as returning an observable created from this array.

For example:

```
timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(val => from([val, val + 1)])).subscribe(val => console.log(val));

timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(val => [val, val + 1])).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I expect the first to work and think it is the correct syntax.

I don't expect the second to work but it actually does and I would like to understand why.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `switchMap`, among other flattening-operators (`mergeMap`, `exhaustMap`, ...), takes an `ObservableLike` as the return type of its projection function.

An `ObservableLike` can be `Observable`, `Promise` or `Array`. If you provide an array, it is converted into a stream of its items - basically the same as if you had used `from`.